# Delete Record Confirmation Message

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

Firstly, my apologies because I'm really very new to this, so please forgive me what some may seem a very basic question/error.

The **extract** of code below, successfully creates a table of records pertinent to the current user.

**Working Solution -** Baylor Rae' worked tirelessly with me over the last 3-4 days to find a solution. All Baylor Rae' was unable to provide a fully successful script, they certainly helped considerably in moving this on . However the full working script below is **Courtesy of jazzman1 @ PHP Freaks**

**Main Script**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('form.delete').submit(function(e){
              console.log('submit'); return false;   
            })
        })
    </script>   

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form.delete').submit(function(e){ 

            e.preventDefault();
            var elem = $(this).closest('.delete');
            var lid = $(this).serialize();
            $.confirm({
                 'title'    : 'Delete Confirmation',
            'message'   : 'You are about to delete this Location. <br />It cannot be restored at a later time! Do you wish to continue?',
                'buttons'   : {
                    'Yes'   : {
                'class' : 'blue',
                'action': function(){
                //elem.slideUp();
                              $.ajax({ 
                            url: 'deletelocation.php', 
                            type: 'POST', 
                            data: lid, 
                            success: function(response) { 
                            console.log('success', response); 
                            }, 
                            error: function() { 
                            console.log('error') 
                            } 
                            }); 
                    }
                },
                'No'    : {
                    'class' : 'gray',
                                        'action': function(){}  // Nothing to do in this case. You can as well omit the action property.

                }
            }
        });

    });

    })
</script>
```

**jqueryconfim.js**

```
  (function($){

        $.confirm = function(params){

            if($('#confirmOverlay').length){
                // A confirm is already shown on the page:
                return false;
            }

            var buttonHTML = '';
            $.each(params.buttons,function(name,obj){

                // Generating the markup for the buttons:

                buttonHTML += '<a href="#" class="button '+obj['class']+'">'+name+'<span></span></a>';

                if(!obj.action){
                    obj.action = function(){};
                }
            });

            var markup = [
                '<div id="confirmOverlay">',
                '<div id="confirmBox">',
                '<h1>',params.title,'</h1>',
                '<p>',params.message,'</p>',
                '<div id="confirmButtons">',
                buttonHTML,
                '</div></div></div>'
            ].join('');

            $(markup).hide().appendTo('body').fadeIn();

            var buttons = $('#confirmBox .button'),
                i = 0;

            $.each(params.buttons,function(name,obj){
                buttons.eq(i++).click(function(){

                    // Calling the action attribute when a
                    // click occurs, and hiding the confirm.

                    obj.action();
                    $.confirm.hide();
                    return false;
                });
            });
        }

        $.confirm.hide = function(){
            $('#confirmOverlay').fadeOut(function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }

    })(jQuery);
```

**Form In Main Script**

```
<form name="delete" id="delete" class="delete">
<input type="hidden" name="lid" id="lid" value="<?php echo $theID ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Delete Record"/>
</form>
```

**deletelocation.php**

```
<?php

    $lid = intval($_POST['lid']);
    $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE locationid='".$lid."'");

    ?>
```

You'll see that the end of the table are four buttons, which, through the `locationsaction.php` script navigate the user to four different screens all linked back to the main table record via the `lid` value. This script is shown below.

I'm now trying to implement a confirmation message for the `Delete` function. The source code for this can be found [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/).

This is where I've become a little unsure about what to do next. I've tried to link the button `on click` event with the name of the `Delete` function, but rather than the confirmation message, the user is taken to a blank screen and the record is deleted.

I've run the JavaScript Console and there are no errors created, so I'm a little unsure about how to continue.

I just wondered whether someone could possibly take a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Add a 'return false;' after the 'delete();' function on the onClick event of the delete button.

Comment: @Virendra, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. I've made the change you suggested and unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem. The record is still deleted without the confirmation message box appearing. Kind regards

Comment: Try changing the button type from 'submit' to 'button'. Also, you don't need the document.ready inside the delete function.

Comment: Hi @Virendra, thank you for your reply. I've made the changes you suggest, and unfortunately, when I now click the button, nothing happens. I've updated the code in my original post to incorporate the changes you suggested. I just wondered whether you could possibly take a look at this please just to make sure I've implemented them correctly. Many thanks and regards

Comment: The return true in your on click should be inside the same quotes as the delete function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Prevent the Redirection

It looks like you're getting the redirection because the form is still submitting. You need to prevent the form from submitting by adding the following line at the beginning of your click event.

```
$('#btn-delete').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this).closest('.item');
```

Calling `e.preventDefault()` will [prevent the browser's default action from occuring](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), in this case submitting the form.

### Changing the way buttons are handled

As far as I can tell `locationsaction.php` redirects to a page based on the value of the button.

A better way to do this would be to create a link to each page and pass the `lid` as a parameter. This is the standard way of linking pages while providing some context for the next page.

**Note:** You will need to change each page to use `$_GET['lid']` instead of `$_SESSION['lid']`.

**Note 2:** It is perfectly valid to "close" and "open" PHP tags in the middle of a page. In the code I provided below I closed PHP so I could write HTML, and reopened PHP when I was done.

```
<?php // this line is for syntax highlighting
/* display row for each user */
$theID = $row['locationid'];
?>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['locationname'] ?></td>
    <td><a href="addimages.php?lid=<?php echo $theID ?>">Images</a></td>
    <td><a href="addfinds.php?lid=<?php echo $theID ?>">Add Finds</a></td>
    <td><a href="locationfinds.php?lid<?php echo $theID ?>">View Finds</a></td>
    <td>
      <form method="post" action="deletelocation.php" class="delete-record">
        <input type="hidden" name="lid" value="<?php echo $theID ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Delete Record" />
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php
```

The only time I didn't use a link was when I linked to the `deletelocation.php` file. This is because [you should never use a GET request when modifying a database](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post/).

Using a POST request is an easy way to prevent [Cross-site Request Forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

### Rename your table column names

I noticed that your column names for `locationid` and `locationname` didn't have any type of separation. I would recommend renaming these to `location_id` and `location_name`.

This applies to your file names as well. You can include an underscore or dash to separate the words in your filename. I usually use an underscore because I think it reads better, but it's your choice.

### POST directly to the delete page

Because you're using AJAX, you can specify the `deletelocation.php` url directly. With the changes I've suggested above, there isn't a reason to keep `locationsaction.php`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'deletelocation.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: $(this).parent().serialize(),
    success: function () {
        img.parent().fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

I also changed how the data was passed. [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) will automatically grab the location id from `input[name=lid]` and create a query string like `lid=1`.

---

**Edit #1**

> If possible, I'd like to keep the locationsaction script. A lot of my pages further down the line rely on a SESSION id, and using a Get isn't an option without re-writing a lot of code.

The way you're using `locationsaction.php` and sessions isn't the way I'd do it. But it's your application structure and you can build it however you like.

> Could I change the button type to button rather than submit, keeping the id the same so the JS code will pick this up?

You can change the type to button, but when javascript is disabled it won't submit the form. In general, you write your page to work without JS, and then write the JS to modify the browser's default behavior.

> Could you also confirm for me whether your AJAX just replaces the top section of my code?

No, I only changed the way you set the `lid`. You still need to include all the JS wrapped around it, I just didn't want to paste the whole block of code.

Comment: I answered the questions you posted, but you deleted your comment.

Comment: Hi @Baylor Rae', thank you for your comments and your help it's greatly appreciated. I've taken note of what you've said and I've made some of the changes you suggested. I have also deleted this line of my code: `success: function () {img.parent().fadeOut('slow');}`Unfortunately, although I select the `delete` record button, the `Confirmation` message does not show on the screen and the record isn't deleted. I've added my updated code to my original post. I just wondered whether you could possibly have a look at it please and let me know where I've gone wrong? Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: @IRHM do you have firebug installed? Or if your using Safari/Chrome can you open the Web Inspector? Either of the debugging tools will show you if you have a JS error and let you see the network requests.

Comment: Hi @Baylor Rae', thank you for coming back to me so quickly. I've just checked this via JavaScript Console and there are no errors being returned. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM okay, if you remove `e.preventDefault()` does it show the confirmation box?

Comment: Hi @Baylor Rae', no unfortunately it doesn't. Upon clicking the button, the browser shows that the `deletelocation` script is being run, but the screen is blank, and the record is not deleted. Kind regards

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14088/discussion-between-baylor-rae-and-irhm)

Answer (score 1):

Observation 1:

```
function delete(){
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Is that really the order of the lines in your code? The jQuery ready hook lies **INSIDE** of your function definition? Or have you, by mistake, posted them here in the wrong order here.

If it's the former case, then please, fix this first before anything else. Otherwise, read on:

1. Why $('.item .delete')? I don't see any markup with class .item? Where is it? Are you sure that this selector matches some elements in the first place? Also, you should use #delete for referencing elements through their id attributes, not .delete, as that looks for elements with the class delete.
2. Your id:delete button and the other buttons are submit type buttons, which means that their click handlers simply will not block the submission flow. You can change all the button types to button, instead of having them as submit. Code example below.
3. Why the declarative onClick on the delete button? Get rid of it.

(Also, you really don't need a form in this case, unless you want to deserialize the form, which doesn't seem like a requirement or intent given your markup).

```
<td><input type='button' name='type' id='details' value='Details'/></td>
<td><input type='button' name='type' id='images' value='Images'/></td>
<td><input type='button' name='type' id='addFinds' value='Add Finds'/></td>
<td><input type='button' name='type' id='viewFinds' value='View Finds'/></td>
<td><input type='button' name='type' id='delete' value='Delete' /></td>
```

And your JS:

```
//please, be careful with the selector.
//it could be that it is not matched at all,
//hence jQuery will not bind to anything
//and nothing will ever fire!
//note the #delete for Id! .delete is for a class!!!!!!
$('.item #delete').click(function () {

    var elem = $(this).closest('.item');

    $.confirm({
        'title': 'Delete Confirmation',
        'message': 'Delete?',
        'buttons': {
            'Yes': {
                'class': 'blue',
                'action': function () {
                    //elem.slideUp();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'locationsaction.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {
                            lid: "VALUE",
                            type: 'Delete' //you need to add the type here!
                        },
                        success: function () {
                            img.parent().fadeOut('slow');
                        }
                    });

                }
            },
            'No': {
                'class': 'gray',
                'action': function () {} // Nothing to do in this case. You can as well omit the action property.
            }
        }
    });
```

Also, you can *redudantly* add a false return to your form's onsubmit event.

Comment: Hi @refactor.me, thankyou for taking the time to put this together. As I said originally I'm very new to JavaScript, and there are clearly quite a few errors. I've added the `submit` buttons contained within the form to allow the user to be taken to the four separate pages through the `locationsaction` script. I think I'm right in saying that if I change these to `buttons` I won't be able to give this functionality? With regards to the JS delete. Could you possibly explain this line for me please. `type: 'Delete' //you need to add the type here!` Kind regards

Comment: No, you can change them to buttons and still have your functionality. If you want to go to a new page, you can do so through the success function, programatically. It's very difficult to make suggestions, when your code is a mix of ajax and traditional submit. It's principally wrong in architecture. Either make it fully Ajaxian, using no traditional form submits at all, or make it completely post based, with no ajax at all. The current mix you have prevents me from making any meaningful suggestions at this point. The type parameter is read in your php script, since I added it into the params.

Comment: Your PHP script can echo back (instead of header redirection) the URL to go to as a string. And in the success function you can redirect through js to that string url.

Comment: HI @reactor.me, thank you for your help with this. I have to be honest and say that I just don't know enough about PHP and AJAX to understand the changes that need to be made. I full appreciate that this makes it difficult for your to continue with suggestions, but I think for now I need to go away and think about this a little more. Once again, many thanks for all your help and guidance it is truly appreciated. kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't find any button of id btn-delete on your form.If your using delete button present in form then change **this**

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete Record" />
```

**to**

```
<input type="button" id="btn-delete" value="Delete Record" />
```

Or your using any other input then make sure that it type is not submit for example

```
<input type="submit" value="Your button" />
```

should be

```
<input type="button" value="Your button" />
```

Comment: Hi @rajesh kakawat, thank you very much for taking the time to reply to my post. I now have a solution which can be seen in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

**u can use jquery ui dialog for confirmation :**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btn-delete').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var elem = $(this).closest('.item'), formSerialize = $(this).parent().serialize(), objParent = $(this).parent();
        $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                    .html('<div><h6>Delete?</h6></div>')
                    .dialog({
                        modal: true, title: 'Delete Confirmation', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                        width: 'auto', resizable: false,
                        buttons: {
                            Yes: function () {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'deletelocation.php',
                                    type: 'post',
                                    data: formSerialize//,
                                    //success: function (data) {
                                    //    objParent.slideUp('slow').remove();
                                    //}
                                });


                                //Or
                                objParent.slideUp('slow').remove();


                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            },
                            No: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        },
                        close: function (event, ui) {
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
                    });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @ThulasiRam, thank you very much for taking the time to reply to my post. I did try your code, but I was unable to get this to work. I have however now got a solution which can be seen in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem isn't anything to do with JavaScript**.

The fundamental problem seems to be that your form's action is to delete the record (regardless of what you've coded in JavaScript). Change the form's action to "." and onsubmit="return false" (which stops the form from doing anything on its own). Now attaching your $.confirm to the appropriate button should work.

Stepping back from this -- you don't need a form at all (or a submit button). Then you wouldn't have to fight the default behavior of a form.

Comment: Hi @podperson, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. I now have my solution which can be seen in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use e.stopPropagation();

```
$('#btn-delete').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: Hi @user1431295, thank you very much for taking the time to reply to my post. I now have my solution which can be seen in my original post.